# Redirect to another HTML page in AngularJS on button click (Ionic)

Tags: html, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am trying to redirect to home.html on click of a button in index.html

```
index.html


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
<title></title>
<link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
<script src="js/home.js"></script>
</head> 
<body ng-app="starter">
<ion-pane>
  <ion-header-bar class="bar-royal">
    <h1 class="title">Index</h1>
  </ion-header-bar>
  <ion-content>
      <div ng-controller="LoginCtrl">
          <button ng-click="login()">Login</button>
      </div>
  </ion-content>
</ion-pane>
</body>
</html>
```

home.js

```
var VLogin = angular.module('starter', ['ionic']);
VLogin.controller('LoginCtrl', ['$scope','$location', function($scope, $location) {

$scope.login = function(){  
$location.path("#/home.html");
};
}]);
```

And here is the hierarchy of both files [image]
$location.path() is not working. Where am I going wrong? TIA.

Comment: Have you setted up your routes?

Answer (score 0):

take a look here: http://learn.ionicframework.com/formulas/navigation-and-routing-part-1/

but the simple answer is that you should set up routes

```
$stateProvider.state('app', {
  url: '',
  templateUrl: 'app.html',
  controller: 'AppCtrl'
  }
}).state('login', {
  url: '/login',
  templateUrl: 'login.html',
  controller: 'LoginCtrl'
  }
})
```

and then I would recommend using the `$state` provider to do something like this

```
login.controller('LoginCtrl', function($scope, $state) {
  $state.go('app',{});
})
```

This is not the EXACT code, but an overview, I would recommed reading the link provided for additional information